# Creating a new database in EF 6.1 with particular name and file locations

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

I am making a small db bootstraping utility for my application. I need to create a database from my model classes, but I want to be able to set DB filenames and locations.

If I do default DbContext instantiation - it will try to create Db named like DataAccessModule.DbContext, and DataBase files (mdf and ldf) will be located in Program Files\SQL... folder. I need to create database with my name (entered by user in UI of bootstraping app) and with mdf and ldf files located in user selected folder.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem? You've got to learn and try a little bit before asking questions like this.

Comment: This connection string I can use to create DB where I want passing SQL statements for this: var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"); But I do not know how do this with EF.

Comment: Please update your question with that extra info, to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a connectionstring like this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlBldr.DataSource = "Server name";
sqlBldr.InitialCatalog = "Database name";
sqlBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true; // or use use + password
sqlBldr.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entBldr = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entBldr.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
entBldr.Metadata = "res://*/";
entBldr.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
```

The EF connection string is `entityBuilder.ToString()`. You simply has to use it in your `DbContextBuilder`. Expose the inherited constructor which receives one parameter:

```
public class MyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(strinc connStr)
        : base(connStr)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
string connectionString = // ... use your connection string builder for this

using(MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
   // ...
}
```

**For choosing file names and location**

Note that you can specify the full path to the `.mdf` file in the [AttachDBFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename.aspx) property of your `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` property instead of using server + database. See [SqlConnectionStringBuilder MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

However, you must ensure that, uf the user specifies a folder, she must have read/write access to that folder.